# How much did the 'The Evil Queen' rule in OUAT?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In Once Upon a Time when Regina became queen, how much did she rule over? Was it only the entirety of the Enchanted Forest?

How long/far did her power extend to? Did she own every single part of land in the Kingdom?

Answer (score 5):

Much like the fairy tales they are based on, the show has been very vague about exactly what Regina was "queen" over when she was the Evil Queen. However, I think it was less than your questions imply, because we've seen more than one king/queen ruling within the bounds of the Enchanted Forest:

- Regina married Snow White's father, King Leopold.
- David (Charming) is the adoptive son of King George.
- David also has to do a favor for King Midas
- Maleficent was nomimally the Queen of her own kingdom.
- Princess Aurora was presumably the daughter of yet another King/Queen.

So, *legally*, I suspect Regina was "only" the Queen of one of several kingdoms in the Enchanted Forest, though the boundaries of that kingdom are never spelled out.

However, Regina was also one of the most powerful rulers in the Enchanted Forest, in particular because of the powerful magic that she possessed. Thus, I assume that once she became The Evil Queen, she would have started to enforce her will beyond it's normal borders. We can sort-of imply this by the fact that no one ever mentions going to other Kings for help with Regina, e.g. Charming never even considers asking his father for help with Regina. In fact, other than flashbacks, we don't see much of anything out of the other rules of the Enchanted Forest (except possibly Maleficent, who appeared to still be ruling over her kingdom when Charming encounters her.)

As far as how much of the land in her kingdom did she own, that's a bit of a tricky question that relates to medieval politics and ownership laws. Generally speaking, if her kingdom were modeled after a typical feudal society (as evidenced by the existence of titular knights), all of the land would have initially been owned by the king/queen, but would have been given to various lords as rewards for their fealty. Those lords would typically own the land and lease it to peasants and other working-class citizens in exchange for taxes or tithes. Exactly how much ownership transferred and what rights the king/queen still had over the land would depends on the specific laws of the country.

But again, in practice, if the king decided he wanted to reclaim ownership of some plot of land in his kingdom, no one would really stop him. Given Regina's strength, that goes even moreso for her.

Comment: Good answer all and all but not what I am looking for at the moment. I don't want my bounty to go to waste so I will award you with it. Thanks though. :)